# Open remote Device file manager using bluetooth [Android]

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer, obex

it's been few days i have been searching for this.

Goal - what i need is to open the file-manager of the device that is connected with my Android device via bluetooth.
i.e Explore file structure from Bluetooth connected device and transfer files.

Done - managed to connect to any device via bluetooth, and and pair them too.

Barrier - after few googling [:P] i found that there is a way to do so.
they says with the help of OBEX and OPP you can access files of bluetooth connected device.
so i tried finding on OBEX implimentation in Android, 
Unfortunatelly i could not manage get help OBEX.

So, now here i am with many questions in 1 question.
that is there any way to Explorer files of Bluetooth connected device.?
am i right that OBEX is the only way to do this?
is there any helpfull documentation/Tutorial that helps to implement OBEX in android?

Comment: are you successfully implement this one or not. Because i am also having the same problem.

Comment: Not exactly because it takes Native development and with OBEX.
still work in progress, skipped because of a high priority work.

Comment: Thanks for your response i am also skipped and use native one.

Comment: Did you find any way to implement this, as I want to do this in my application?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FTP profile(file transfer profile) which uses OBEX, can find code at [here](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/external/gigabyte/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/tree/src/com/android/bluetooth?h=jb_2.1.3.7). Thanks to QCOM for open-source code, check if you need to have RFCOMM channel registration and other details

Comment: Do you have a proper example of what i am seeking of..?